# How to get all users who wrote to the bot in telegram?

Tags: c#, bots

I am using library for c # Telegram.Bot. Can I somehow get the ChatID of all users who have ever written to the bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with standard API methods.

You must save user in database when you receive messages.